# Find the value of a complex function satisfying a giving condition. (GATE 2008)

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a very easy question of complex analysis. I do not know to solve it.

Let $S$ be the disk $|z| < 3$ in the complex plain and $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $f(1 + i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n} ) = -\frac{2}{n^2}$ for all natural number $n$. What is the value of $f(\sqrt{2})$?

Two points I am getting trivially. $f(1) = 0$ and $f(1 + i\sqrt{2}) = -2$. Nothing else.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's an application of the identity theorem. Which (simple) function $g$ has the same values as $f$ in the indicated points. And why does it follow that $f = g$?

Comment: how can you conclude that $f(1)=0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer :  Can we just take $g$ such that $g(\frac{1}{n})=−\frac{2}{n^2}$.... does that help? Can you please extend your hint a bit more!

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik One could use such a $g$, but it's more direct if you choose $g$ to satisfy $g\left(1+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right) = -\frac{2}{n^2}$ for all $n$. Can you see a simple function with that property? Then you use the identity theorem to conclude that that is $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : I am sorry I am unable to grasp what you are trying to convey :(

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik If it were $h\left(i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right) = -\frac{2}{n^2}$, would you see what $h$ is then?

Comment: i am sorry I am not getting it.. may be it is not my cup of coffee! :(

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry for late response. I am getting the function $g(z) = - Im(z)^2$ as $g$ but it is not analytic. To apply the uniqueness theorem $g$ must be analytic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

$$g(z) = (z-1)^2.$$

Since $f\bigl(1 + i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\bigr) = g\bigl(1 + i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\bigr)$ for all positive integers $n$ and the sequence $1 + i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ has a limit point in $\mathbb{C}$, the identity theorem asserts that $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in S$. Hence

$$f(\sqrt{2}) = (\sqrt{2} - 1)^2 = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}\,.$$

Comment: This is the main point to identify the function $g$ which we could not find out. Thank you.